# UIImagePickerController keeps “recording” video after dismissed

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I’m experiencing somewhat weird behaviour of `UIImagePickerController` which I use for capturing video. After a video has been recorded and picked by the user and the view controller is dismissed, a tap on one of my `UITextField`s makes the app enter the “record” mode again, but without the `UIImagePickerController` being visible. All what happens is the volume rocker becomes the stop/record button (it plays the respective chime when pressed), the keyboard stops “clicking” (as it always does while there’s a recording in process), and when I close the app I can see the red **recording** status bar flashing for a moment.

Again, no `UIImagePickerController` is present at that moment, but the app acts as if it’s recording something. Pressing the volume rockers to actually “record” some clips doesn’t save them in the library however (contrary to what happens in my `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method).

Here is how I initialise the picker:

```
self.cameraController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.cameraController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.cameraController.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];
self.cameraController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480;
self.cameraController.delegate = self;
```

Here is my `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` (it is shared with another `UIImagePickerController` which is used for the user photo library, hence some unrelated logic):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // Dismiss the picker
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [picker isEqual:self.photoLibraryController])
        [self.photoLibraryPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    else
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Save the media URL
    if (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL])
        [self.uploadDataDictionary setObject:info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] forKey:@"mediaURL"];

    // Identify the source of the media (camera or library)
    [self.uploadDataDictionary setObject:picker forKey:@"sourcePicker"];

    // If it comes from the camera picker, save the video in the library
    NSString *videoPath = [info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    if ([picker isEqual:self.cameraController] && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath)) {
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath, self, nil, nil);
    }

}
```

And the tap reaction for the text field which triggers the above weirdness:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    float textFieldPosition = textField.frame.origin.y - 20;
    [self.formView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, textFieldPosition) animated:YES];
}
```

I also have a bunch of other buttons and a textview in that part of the app, but none of them make it enter this weird “background recording” mode.

Also, I use ARC for this project, obviously.

Any idea what could be the cause of the problem?